# How to login with mechanize when no password control

Tags: python, post, authentication, mechanize-python

i'm new to python and mechanize, and i try to login to a site where the password control doesn't seem to appear.

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(url)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
print(browser.form)
```

the print is :

```
<POST http://*****.com application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <HiddenControl(login=submit) (readonly)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>=Ok) (readonly)>>
```

I don't really understand how can make it work. 
Using inspector on the webpage give me this :

```
<form action="" onsubmit="javascript:showBusyLayer()" method="post">

        <input id="login" type="hidden" value="submit" name="login"></input>

        Login

        <br></br>
        <input class="log_input" type="text" name="login_name"></input>
    </form>

</div>
<div style="float:left">

    Password

    <br></br>
    <input class="log_input" type="password" name="login_password"></input>

</div>
<div style="float:left;padding:14px 0 0 4px">

    <input class="log_submit" type="submit" value="Ok" onclick="submit();"></input>

</div>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: im not sure that mechanize is able to handle the javascript, maybe try https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html#simple-usage?

Comment: Looks like the `input[name=login_password]` isn't contained within the `<form>...</form>` tags.

Comment: What's the `</br>` for?

Comment: thx x29a, selenium did the job well !!